# How to include dynamic code in rails 3.2 model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3.2 app, we want to keep the code of workflow definition code dynamic in a model. Here is the workflow def code:

```
include Workflow
workflow do     
  state :new do
    event :submit, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
  end
  state :being_reviewed do
    event :approve, :transitions_to => :approved
    event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
  end
  state :approved
  state :rejected
end
```

The code above is returned as `string` stored in variable `workflow_pdef`. Our question is how to `dynamically` include the code above in a model with `eval(workflow_pdef)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we did:

```
include Workflow
Worflow do
  eval(workflow_pdef)
end
```

Then the string of workflow_pdef is:

```
workflow_pdef = "     
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :approve, :transitions_to => :approved
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :approved
    state :rejected
  "
```

The function part of a workflow definition could become dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

```
workflow_pdef = <<-CODE
  include Workflow
  workflow do     
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :approve, :transitions_to => :approved
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :approved
    state :rejected
  end
CODE

# Included on every instance of A
class A; end
A.class_eval workflow_pdef

# Included just in instance 'b'
class B; end
b = B.new
b.instance_eval workflow_pdef
```

Comment: The pdef string has to be executed within a model.

Comment: You replace class 'A' or instance 'b' with `self.class` or `self` to run on the current model